# PGAdmin III Server Status Error: Could not read directory "pg_log" No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

Running PostgreSQL 9.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 and pgAdmin III 1.18.1 on Windows 7.

I tried `Tools->Server Status` and I get an error:

> "Could not read directory "pg_log" No such file or directory"

I don't see any answers online. The server is mostly setup with default settings (for logging). The user I'm connecting with through pgAdmin is a superuser level account.

Purpose of use: monitoring what will become a live system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your client (Windows) is running on a different machine than your server (Ubuntu).

You cannot read the **remote file system**. Inspecting the logs only works if your client is on the same machine (or has access to the remote file system by way of some advanced trickery.)

To suppress the error message remove the log file from the display.
In the Server Status window press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>
Or uncheck `View -> Logfile`.